# What's the best practice for transforming content inside Electron WebView?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to load content from Electron's WebView and transform it before rendering.

I am wondering what's the best practice for this kind of thing. Should I run something like `executeJavascript` after loading? That doesn't feel clean.

I wonder if there's a way to hijack the traffic in the main process and transform before returning..

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by transform it before rendering.

Comment: for example, transforming JSON string into a navigatable tree, or transform markdown into html, etc.

Comment: I just read through the docs for the WebView class and I do not see any other way to access the document runtime environment besides the `executeJavascript` function.

Comment: If this your own content, or third party?